# Formatting Time without decimals

Tags: r, time

I currently have a large data set with the variable time formatted as such: "15:36:44.874541+0000", for one example.

I want to remove the decimals and just have it as "15:36:44" for every variable in the set.

Comment: can u provide a small sample of set including variable time.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it into `POSIXct` type and then extract only time with `format`.

```
x <- '15:36:44.874541+0000'
format(as.POSIXct(x, format = "%T"), "%T")
#[1] "15:36:44"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the perfect and most elegant way of doing it, but you can split by "." and keep the first item.

You can write:

```r
c <- "15:36:44.874541+0000"
df <- data.frame(Time = rep(c,5))

library(rebus)
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Time2 = unlist(strsplit(as.character(Time),"\\."))[1])

                  Time    Time2
1 15:36:44.874541+0000 15:36:44
2 15:36:44.874541+0000 15:36:44
3 15:36:44.874541+0000 15:36:44
4 15:36:44.874541+0000 15:36:44
5 15:36:44.874541+0000 15:36:44
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to strip that time and format it.

> current_time <- "15:36:44.874541+0000"
>
> formated_time <- format(strptime(time, format = "%H:%M:%S"), "%H:%M:%S")
>
> formated_time

[1] "15:36:44"

Answer (score 0):

We can use `strptime` with `strftime`

```
strftime(strptime(x, "%T"), "%T")
#[1] "15:36:44"
```

#### data

```
x <- '15:36:44.874541+0000'
```